# Authenticating using Social Business Java SDK - erroneous SSL error when login

Tags: ibm-sbt

I'm developing an iWidget that needs to read both Public and "My" Communities so requires authentication but cannot use the Javascript SDK functions as the iWidget's Dojo version must be 1.4 (long story). Using the SDK's Java BasicEndpoint class looks like an alternate way to login withouta UI prompt. I created a new BasicEndpoint and set the same attributes as configured in sbt.properties, and set it as the new Endpoint for the Community Service:

CommunityService svc = new CommunityService();
svc.setEndpoint(basicEndpoint);

I used BasicEndpoint's login method to pass username and password but the call to basicEndpoint.login generated this error:

com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientServicesException: Error while executing the REST service http://www.ourdevserverdomain.com/communities/service/atom/communities/my
....
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Strange because we're not even using SSL against our dev server. There is a method for checking if SSL Certificate trusting is enabled which I'd like to try at least in development mode but I don't see way to set that property:

boolean bypassSSL=basicEndpoint.isForceTrustSSLCertificate();

Is there a method to bypass SSL checking, or a way to set other properties on the EndPoint to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 0):

it's highly unlikely your URL was HTTP:// so I'm assuming it's https://... and just an error in editing...

so in the server that's hosting the SDK, you'll want to add the signer of the connections server...

is it tomcat? if so, adding a signer means adding it to the keystore for the java that's hosting the tomcat service.

if it's websphere, you'll want to add it using
Open you WebSphere Console

Go to Security

Click SSL certificate and key management

Click Key stores and certificates

Click CellDefaultTrustStore

Click Signer Certificates

Click Retrieve From Port

Enter the HOSTNAME of your Connections Server, and the port, if it's 443, use 443

Click Ok

Click Save / Close

Then Sync the Nodes (you can do it under environment. Then restart the Connections Server (you might not have to do this step)

Retry your command

Comment: That resolved the SSL error. I now get an "Error while executing the REST service https://XXX.YYY.com/communities/service/atom/communities/my" but that url in the browser prompts and logs  in successfully. Code includes: 
BasicEndpoint basicEndpoint=new BasicEndpoint();
then .setUrl, .setAuthenticationPage, .setAuthenticationService and .setApiVersion to the values in the default Endpoint in sbt.properties
...
CommunityService svc = new CommunityService();
svc.setEndpoint(basicEndpoint);
basicEndpoint.login(USER,PWORD);

Is this valid and what else can I configure to authenticate from Java ?